# Hide/modify string in listView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am making a program in which users can modify remote files. I put the selected files (depending on some predefined criteria) in a listView, but I display only the file names, not full filepaths.

The problem I get however, is that when a user would double-click on an item, it should open another window to modify that item.

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    account = File.ReadAllLines("\\\\myremoteserver\\ftp\\"+listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text+".txt");   
    Form3 passForm = new Form3();
    passForm.ShowDialog();
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("\\\\myremotserver\\ftp\\","*.txt", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s));
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the files are all in different subfolders, so if I leave the code as is, it will not display the correct content of the file. For example, the file is called test1.txt, it is placed in `myremoteserver\ftp\testfolder\test1.txt`, but with my program, it will try to find the file in `myremoteserver\ftp\test1.txt`.

What I am asking is, if it is possible to modify the listView in such a way, that the full file path is always saved, but only the file names are displayed? I do not want the user to see the complete file path of the files, just the file names.

Comment: if listview items have a `.tag` property you could save the full path in there

Comment: or better add a typed item in the listView1.Items.Add method and use the DisplayMember (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx) to just show the name in the list view.

Comment: I will most likely use the .tag property, thank you, it works, I just had to swap the `foreach` loop for a `for` loop. @Digvijay why would that be better?

Comment: This (using .Tag ) works as long as its just strings you need to work with - however as soon as you realize you need to update the list using INotifyPropertyChange the tag approach fails!

Comment: The list will most likely never be updated, as I only use it to display the files on program startup, based on the parameters defined by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Tag property of the ListViewItem

So to create items...

```
foreach (string s in files)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s));
    lvi.Tag = s;
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Then in event handler...

```
account = File.ReadAllLines("\\\\myremoteserver\\ftp\\"+listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag +".txt);
```